# How to give inline focus style to an href that wraps to the next line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

I've created some focus states for all the links on my site. The button focus is great. I'm struggling to add an inline focus state to a link when the link is wrapped. If you look at the example, if a link doesn't wrap, then it's fine. But, when it wraps, I end up with a focus "square" around the start of the link, but it doesn't extend for the entire link.

**How can I make the wrapped link look like the non-wrapped link?**

Here's a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/ZEKoGdV)** if you prefer.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute("href", "#")
});
```

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  position: relative;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title {
  max-width: 500px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before,
input[type='checkbox']::before,
input[type='radio']::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 0px #005fec;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: blur(4px);
}

a:focus-visible::before,
input[type='checkbox']:focus-visible::before,
input[type='radio']:focus-visible::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 2px #005fec;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">a button</a>
  <div class="title">
    <h4><a href="#">This is going to be some wrapped text, but unfortunately</a> it doesn't wrap it in an inline fashion.
    </h4>
    <h4><a href="#">This is some inline</a> text. Works fine.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only outline can give you the result you want.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(a[href])").forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute("href", "#")
});
```

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  position: relative;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title {
  max-width: 500px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a,
input[type='checkbox'],
input[type='radio'] {
  outline: solid 0px #005fec;
  outline-offset:0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:focus-visible,
input[type='checkbox']:focus-visible,
input[type='radio']:focus-visible {
  outline: solid 2px #005fec;
  outline-offset:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">a button</a>
  <div class="title">
    <h4><a href="#">This is going to be some wrapped text, but unfortunately</a> it doesn't wrap it in an inline fashion.
    </h4>
    <h4><a href="#">This is some inline</a> text. Works fine.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I need to maintain the border radius that's currently showing in my OP. I can't add border-radius with an outline property.

Comment: @Millhorn I know, you have to drop some requirement. Either the radius or make it work with inline element. I doubt you can have both of them (without a hacky code)